# How do you get to the privileges page?

Tags: support, status-completed

I wanted to check what I can/can't do on the privileges page but i can't find a link to it anywhere. So.... where's do I click?

Answer (score 1):

That's a good point, we should probably link to it somewhere -- but when you pass a reputation boundary you'll get a message pointing to it as well:

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/privileges

Comment: might i suggest just making your rep on your user page clickable to that page? since one depends on the other and all. or really one just someplace on the user page would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: [Hint hint](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67333/where-is-the-link-to-my-privileges-page/67615#67615).  The user profile page would also be a good place for it.